# on click en lista generada con click con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una lista que se genera con un enlace y quiero que al hacer clic en un li de esta lista aparezca un alert.

Tengo esto pero no funciona

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function(){
    $(".add").append('<ul class="lista">' +
          '<li>Coffee</li>' +
          '<li>Tea</li>' +
          '<li>Milk</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    );
  });

    $(".lista li").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });

});
```

Comment: Esta pregunta la has hecho dos veces, considera eliminarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque son elementos creados dinámicamente, es decir que no lo alcanzas normalmente ya que fueron insertados en un segundo momento en el DOM.

Para llegar a esos botones tendrias que hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#table").append("<tr><td><button id='enviar' type='button'>enviar</button></td></tr>");

      $("#table").on("click", "#enviar", function(){
          console.log("dato enviado");
      });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

para incorporarlo en tu codigo tendrias que hacer lo siguiente :

```
$("#IdElementoPadre").on("click", "#IdTarget", function(){});
```

en cual el elemento padre tiene que ser un elemento que este presente en el DOM, osea ya definido en el `HTML` y el `target` sería el botón.

Funciona también con clases, exitos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes también llamar al evento `on` después de hacer el `append`. En ese momento ya tienes tus elementos en el `DOM` por lo que puedes asociarles el evento `click`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function(){
    $(".add").append('<ul class="lista">' +
          '<li>Coffee</li>' +
          '<li>Tea</li>' +
          '<li>Milk</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    );
    
     $(".lista li").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });
  });

   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>asdf</a>
<div class="add"></div>
```